# Uncaught Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a redux state and its initial value calculated based on a value in `localStorage`. As we cannot access it in SSR it cause the following error in client side

```
Uncaught Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
```

I have two independent questions

1. Is there anyway to suppress this error? It's an expected behaviour and I don't count it an error
2. Is there any way share the value of localStorage to the server?

Comment: 1. You should not suppress this error since it is important. 2. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787577/how-get-jwt-token-from-local-storage-in-server-side-component/77787818#77787818) answer I wrote that covers the same topic