# How get jwt token from local storage in server side component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt, server-side-rendering

After login api response jwt token, and i store it in local storage. Then from server component i want to get this token to api request. How? I use nextjs14.

I using context to store token. But don't know that it is best practice or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the `localStorage` object inside a server component since it is a browser specific API. However, there are different approaches that can be used when working with server components.

**Alternatives**

You may want to have a look at the [iron-session](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session) package. Inside your server component you can then access your created session like this:

```
export default async function Page(): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  // inside your session object you can then access the jwt
  // via the defined property.
  const session = await getIronSession(cookies(), sessionConfig);
  return <>My token: {session?.jwt}</>;
}
```

Because these sessions are stateless and live on the server exclusively you can use something [server-actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) if you want to fetch something on the client side.

```
export default async function Page(): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const session = await getIronSession(cookies(), sessionConfig);

  const fetchData = async (userInput: string) => {
    "use server"; // <- turns this function into a server action
    const response = await fetch(`https://example.com?q=${userInput}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.jwt}` },
    });
    return await response.json();
  }

  return <MyClientComponent onFetch={fetchData} />
}
```

As you can see in the example above, the server action receives a `userInput` that has been entered by the user on the client side and fetches the data on the server without the need for the token to ever be on the client side.